# How can I select all DIVs with querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to call all `div`s because `TUTTIiDIV` is already an array. When I run this code the console looks okay, but the code doesn't work as expected.

How can I select all the elements of the array `TUTTIiDIV`?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var TUTTIiDIV = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  document TUTTIiDIV.onclick = function() {
    coloraicontorni()
  }

}); //END DOMcontentLoaded

function coloraicontorni() {
  var TUTTIiDIV = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  for (i = 0; i <= TUTTIiDIV.length; i++) {
    TUTTIiDIV[i].classList.add('contorno');
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#rosso {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blu {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#giallo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contorno {
  border: 8px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="rosso"></div>
<div id="blu"></div>
<div id="giallo"></div>
```

Comment: huh `document
    TUTTIiDIV
    .onclick=function(){`

Comment: You can not assign an event handler to an HTML collection....

Comment: so how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegation from the closest container to choose a click on anything in that container

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    [...this.querySelectorAll("div")] // the "this" is the container
    .forEach(div => div.classList.add('contorno'));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#rosso {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blu {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#giallo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contorno {
  border: 8px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="rosso"></div>
  <div id="blu"></div>
  <div id="giallo"></div>
</div>
```

If you ONLY want to click the divs, do this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "DIV") { // only if we click a div in the container
      [...this.querySelectorAll("div")] // the "this" is the container
      .forEach(div => div.classList.add('contorno'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#rosso {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blu {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#giallo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contorno {
  border: 8px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="rosso"></div>
  <div id="blu"></div>
  <div id="giallo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, I've adjusted your function.

Run the snippet below:

```js
var TUTTIiDIV = document.querySelectorAll("div");


for (let i = 0; i < TUTTIiDIV.length; i++) {
//addEventListener "click" for each div that you are looping through with querySelectorAll
  TUTTIiDIV[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    TUTTIiDIV[i].classList.toggle("contorno");
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#rosso {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blu {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#giallo {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contorno {
  border: 8px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="rosso">
</div>
<div id="blu">
</div>
<div id="giallo">
</div>
```

Comment: Looping over all the `div` elements just to assign the same event handler is wasteful. Use "event delegation" instead. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Give me feedback if u too. ;)

Edit after Scott Marcus comment.

```
const tuttiDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if(event.target.nodeName === "DIV"){
    tuttiDiv.forEach((div) => {
      div.classList.toggle("contorno");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `for/of`, just loop over the node list returned from `.querySelectorAll()` with `.forEach()`. See my answer for this.

Comment: Looping over all the `div` elements just to assign the same event handler is wasteful. Use "event delegation" instead. See my answer for example.

Comment: Okey I understood what you meant and edited so that others would not make the same mistake. I'm new in SO. Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: It's not that your code was a "mistake", it just wasn't as efficient as it could be and I was just pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out TUTTIiDIV is a collection and so it won't have an `onclick` property to set, however your `coloraicontorni` function correctly loops over each item in the collection and modifies its `classList`.

But, better yet, use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to more simply solve this.

Also, you should only have your `<script>` referenced once and that should be just before the closing `body` tag so that by the time the `script` is processed, all the HTML will have been parsed. This removes the need for the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

See comments below:

```js
// If your <script> is located just before the closing body tag,
// then it is not necessary to set up the DOMContentLoaded event
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

// Instead of setting up an event handler on each <DIV>, just
// set up a single event handler on the document and when the
// click events bubble up to it, check event.target to see
// which element actually triggered the event. This is called
// "event delegation".

let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if it was a <div> that triggered the event
  if(event.target.nodeName === "DIV"){
    // Loop over all the <div> elements in the collection
    divs.forEach(function(div){
      div.classList.add("contorno");  // Add the class
    });
  }
});
```

```css
*    { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { background-color: antiquewhite; }
#rosso {
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#blu {
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

#giallo {
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contorno { border: 8px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="rosso"></div>
<div id="blu"></div>
<div id="giallo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let divs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('div')];
   divs.forEach(div => {
       div.addEventListener('click',function(){
            div.classList.toggle('border');
       })
   });
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.border{
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='d' style="background: red;"></div>
<div class='d' style="background: green;"></div>
<div class='d' style="background: blue"></div>
```